# Need help to parse file

Tags: python, linux, bash

We have a file with below information:

```
Files: *
License: LGPL-2+
Files: po/bg.po
       po/eo.po
       po/sl.po
       po/sv.po
       po/th.po
       po/tr.po
License: LGPL-2+
Files: po/te.po
License: LGPL-2+
Files: po/vi.po
License: LGPL-2+
Files: tls/tests/mock-pkcs11.*
License: LGPL-2.1+
Files: dbus-1/dconf-dbus-1.*
       tests/gsettings.c tests/dbus1.c
License: GPL-3+
Files: debian/*
License: GPL-3
Files: po/fi.po
License: LGPL-2+
```

I want to combine all files which are under same license, looking for the output in below format :

```
LGPL-2+(*,po/bg.po,po/eo.po,po/sl.po,po/sv.po,po/th.po,po/tr.po,po/fi.po,po/te.po,po/vi.po),LGPL-2.1+(tls/tests/mock-pkcs11.*),
GPL-3+(dbus-1/dconf-dbus-1.*,tests/gsettings.c tests/dbus1.c),GPL-3(debian/*)
```

----or----

```
LGPL-2+(*,po/bg.po,po/eo.po,po/sl.po,po/sv.po,po/th.po,po/tr.po,po/fi.po,po/te.po,po/vi.po)
LGPL-2.1+(tls/tests/mock-pkcs11.*)
GPL-3+(dbus-1/dconf-dbus-1.*,tests/gsettings.c tests/dbus1.c)
GPL-3(debian/*)
```

Any helps appreciated.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post the code?

Comment: Tried this sed command :sed ':a;N;s/\n/,/;ta' file | se 's/,Files/\nFILES:/g'
I'm getting below output , but not as per expectation :

    Files: *,License: LGPL-2+
    FILES:: po/bg.po,       po/eo.po,       po/sl.po,       po/sv.po,       po/th.po,       po/tr.po,License: LGPL-2+
    FILES:: po/fi.po,License: LGPL-2+
    FILES:: po/te.po,License: LGPL-2+
    FILES:: po/vi.po,License: LGPL-2+
    FILES:: tls/tests/mock-pkcs11.*,License: LGPL-2.1+

Looking further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk to rescue:

```
$1=="License:"{
  a[$2]=a[$2](a[$2]?",":"")f;
  next
}
$1=="Files:"{
  f=$2
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    f=f (f?",":"")$i
}
END{
  for(i in a)
    printf "%s(%s)\n",i,a[i]
}
```

The variable `f` is filled with filenames. When the keyword `License:` is found, all files in the variable `f` are copied to the array `a`.

The `END` statement just print the content of the array.

Note the `(...?...:...)` which is the inline C style `if ... then ... else ...` statement used for adding the comma `,` inbetween each filename.

Comment: Thank olive, this is working for me.However one file (tests/dbus1.c) is missing from output i.e. expected:"GPL-3+(dbus-1/dconf-dbus-1.*,tests/gsettings.c tests/dbus1.c)" but getting:"GPL-3+(dbus-1/dconf-dbus-1.*,tests/gsettings.c)"

Comment: Now getting the "tests/dbus1.c" file which was missing earlier. However all files observing 2 times in output. e.g. GPL-3(debian/*,debian/*)

Comment: @SandipGiri That time, it should be ok

Comment: I have appended new license ("BSD (2 clause)") to the input file. For license "BSD (2 clause)", we are getting "BSD" only, but we expected : "BSD (2 clause)". Can you please provide your suggestion ?

Comment: @SandipGiri Remove the space from the string to have something like `BSD_2_clause`. If not possible, please another question since this is beyond the scope of this question.